# Saving Workbook in Multiple Locations VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two files:

X - File where I am running the Macro from.
Y - File with template where I save to multiple locations.

How can I do:

Y.SaveAs Filename:="File1.xlsx"

Y.SaveAs Filename:="File2.xlsx"

Y.SaveAs Filename:="File3.xlsx"

The only solution I seem to find is using ActiveWorkbook after the first save but from what I read it is a bad habit to do so. Is there another way?

Edit: The Filenames are:= "File(" & SomeDateString & ").xlsx"

Code:

```
Dim Y as Workbook
Set Y = "C:\MyFiles\FileTemp.xlsx"
-X Generates Data to Y
Dim datenow as date
dim datestring as string
datenow = now
datestring = Format(datenow, "Short Date")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Y.SaveCopyas Filename:="C:\MyData1\Budget("& datestring &").xlsx"
Y.SaveCopyas Filename:="C:\MyData2\Budget("& datestring &").xlsx"
Y.SaveCopyas Filename:="C:\MyData3\Budget("& datestring &").xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your workbook to a variable and use that.

```
Sub xxxx()
   Dim y as workbook

   Set y  = Workbooks("Workbook name")

   Y.SaveCopyAs Filename:="File(" & SomeDateString & ").xlsx"

   Y.SaveCopyAs Filename:="File(" & SomeDateString & ").xlsx"

   Y.SaveCopyAs Filename:="File(" & SomeDateString & ").xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Gives me a 1004 Runtime error for some reason. I forgot one important detail I will put in to the main post.

Comment: See edit. I think using `SaveCopyAs` should take care of the issue.

Comment: Also, beware that if you don't specify a file path along with the name, it will use the active directory.

Comment: I am getting random errors of 400 and runtime 1004. I am perplexed by this. The file generated at error time is in a non-existent folder and only has part of SomeDateString and the ")"

Comment: I have included the file path within the name but just generalized the filename

Comment: You should specify a full path, something like `"C:\File(" & SomeDateString & ").xlsx"`

Comment: Can you post your actual code then? It's hard to say what the issue is when you haven't posted your full code.

Comment: `Set Y = "C:\MyFiles\FileTemp.xlsx"` This is incorrect. If the workbook is closed, use: `Set Y = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFiles\FileTemp.xlsx")`. If it is already open, use `Set Y = Workbooks("FileTemp.xlsx")`.

Comment: Sorry in a rush I forgot about that. But I discovered the answer it was the way i formatted the date and incorporated it into an excel file. There were / marks which created errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The date format used a / mark which truncated my naming.